# Scaling printable pages

Tags: delphi, pdf, printing, rendering

This may be a terminology issue, I'm not sure; I don't do much rendering to print devices, so I'm not clear what I actually want or need.

I'm extracting some scan images from a DB, including TIFFs, JPGs, and PDFs, that are sent to a laser printer. The application requires a header space on each page where a barcode and some identifier info is printed, so it scales everything to 90% of its original image size. The TIFF and JPG images print fine.

I'm actually adding the ability to print PDFs right now. I'm using a library from Gnostice with a function GetBitmap for a PDF object (TgtExProPDFDocument) that has width and height parameters that appear to default to 72 DPI. The default settings are actually scaling the image to ~60% before printing it, and the resulting printed page is so small it's illegible. I'm not scaling it, but if I did apply the normal 90% scaling, it would be even smaller.

We're also using an old lib from Joe C. Hecht called PrnDib, and it has a variety of functions to render a bitmap to the printer, but no manual or useful comments in the source file.  One function I'm using has a parameter 'autoscale' that prints the PDF page so it covers the entire page. That's nice, but it's still rather fuzzy and hard to read. And we need that header area at the top.

I'm trying to understand what might affect this. The TIFF and JPG images don't seem to be affected the same way.

For the PrintxxxBitmapyyy methods, I can specify all kinds of things.

What I'm trying to figure out is whether I should be taking the width + height of the printer page, and DPI settings, and using them for the rendering function? The defaults are not working, but the PDF itself clearly has a DPI, height, and width (presumably a full printed page).

I know this is a horrible question because I really don't know what to ask. What I'm trying to figure out is how to render the PDF at 90% of the printed page's area. I hope someone here with expertise in printing can help out.

Note that we're using both D7 and 10.2 Tokyo, although I think the issues I'm dealing with have been around in Windows forever.

Comment: I've read this three times and I'm still not sure what your question is.  Are you trying to print 72 dpi images to a laser printer that is at least 300/600 dpi?  Maybe refine your question to one part, and post that, along with any code you have.

Comment: What DPI resolution was used when those PDF documents were scanned? I don't know of any scanner that would be scanning with only 72 DPI. Even early consumer scanners used at least 100 DPI scanning resolution or more. Nowadays most comonly used resolution for scanning documents is 150 DPI when no OCR is needed. But if documents are being scanned with intention of OCR recognition then the scanning resolution used is at least 200 DPI or more...

Comment: ... So I suggest you first check which scanning resolution was used for those PDF's and try setting DPI property of your PDF component acordingly and then work from there.

Comment: scaling to a smaller size then back to a larger size is bound to produce fuzzy images, so you need to avoid scaling sown to 60% in the first place. You could try making your page size 50% bigger and playing around that way, but it is a bit of a kludge.

Comment: The 72 DPI is the DEFAULT DPI PARAMETER SETTING on the GetBitmap function. I have no idea why it's 72. That's just what it is. Is it possible to read the DPI setting that the original image was created with? I know that at 100 DPI a full-page image printed at native resolution on a laser printer is about the size of a business card on the printed page. I don't know why the image is being scaled down to 60%, but maybe it's because of that 72 DPI default setting? This is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: 72 DPI is historic. It's the early macs' screen resolution - which matched early printers' point per inch resolution. Used for a while for *web graphics* since primary target was computer screens, not relevant any more. Windows bitmaps might or might not have a specified resolution in the [header](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd183376%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). If it exists, printing software may or may not honor it (depending on settings). What matters for you is to determine how many pixels you need to fill the page. That depends on printer resolution.